# QuickTime JavaScript API docs?

Tags: javascript, quicktime

I'm currently trying to add a QuickTime player via the Apple-provided JavaScript utility as described in the [HTML Scripting Guide for QuickTime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_Document/ScriptingHTML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-2-HTMLScripting) Apple docs to my web application.

The only problem I have is that there is no JavaScript API documentation - there is another article in the Apple Docs on [Controlling Media with JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH3-SW1) - but this only covers the HTML `<audio>` tag JavaScript API, which is different form the QuickTime Embed/Object JavaScript API.

Dose anybody know where to find the QuickTime JavaScript API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It genuinely appears this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/RM/Fundamentals/QTOverview/QTOverview_Document/QuickTimeOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000992-CH1g-TheQuickTimeAPI) is [no longer available](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=QuickTime&filter=Guides) only the [HTML Scripting guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_HTML/QTScripting_HTML_AIntroduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001525-CH202-SW1)(, and I've compared them, they are not the same) via Apple.

Here is the first, last and only HTML-Version backup-copy on archive.org (document was last updated on 2008-02-08 and archived on 2010-10-14):
https://web.archive.org/web/20101014174405/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/aQTScripting_Javascro_AIntro/Introduction%20to%20JavaScript%20QT.html

However.. after (quite) some more digging.. I found a backup of the original pdf, (again, document was last updated 2008-02-08, archived on 2012-09-16, this is the last/youngest version I could find):
https://web.archive.org/web/20120916183252/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/QTScripting_JavaScript.pdf

For future generations who wish to verify the pdf-document downloaded from a 'less-trusted' source (I just wish I had such info when backtracking ancient official specs):

- filesize: 336906 bytes
- MD5: 4575cebea8cf2f1c4df9edb20f951edf
- SHA1: f1956f2c45fedc6eda95b825a3170e7b7b9a28d5
- CRC32: ef814f0d

Comment: Thanks! The only thing that I could find was a QuickTime reference from what seems to be 2000 - https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/QuickTime/REF/QT41_HTML/QT41WhatsNew-72.html.

Answer (score 1):

I found JavaScript Scripting Guide for QuickTime [here](http://www.filibeto.org/unix/macos/lib/dev/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/QTScripting_JavaScript.pdf) from 2007.
A bit old. If you found a newer one in the meanwhile let me now.